# Get WooCommerce product URL based featured_image in WP Rest API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WP Rest API in a React app. I am trying to access the product featured image in the Rest API. It already comes with the featured_media id, for example: `featured_media: 15195`, but that doesn't really help me show the image. I have been trying to figure out how to add a field in the Rest API to return the product image URL.

Is there a way to do this, or a resource that would be helpful?

Comment: what endpoint you are using to retrieve the product? or a product ? Are you just trying to get a single product image using rest api  /

Comment: I am using ```/wp/v2/product?per_page=100``` to get all the products, there are fewer than 100

Comment: try using => `http://yoururl/wp-json/wc/v3/products/` - this will give you all products data in array with containing each products_Images as well.

Comment: i am getting 
```
code "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view"
message "Sorry, you cannot list resources."
data 
status 401
```
I didn't set the Woocommerce section up, someone else did, is there something i should be logged into? i am logged into the WP site though

Comment: are you using basic authentication ?

Comment: I actually have no idea. I will try to find that out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222074/discussion-between-always-helping-and-kb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **two** options you can use - either you can modify you current product `rest api` URL to have the images `url` being returned to in one call or you can modify your `functions.php` by adding this code below:

**Modify functions.php**

```
//Register new route - fetch product and its image together in one request
function product_route() {
    register_rest_field( 
        'product',
        'featured_image_url',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'getImagesUrl',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'product_route' );

//get images with URL
function getImagesUrl( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    //get products image URL
    $product_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $object->id ), 'large' );
    
    //return image url
    return $product_img_url['0'];
}
```

**You can use fetch in single request like this after adding the above code in to functions.php**

```
fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/product")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    //setProducts(data); //set state
});
```

**Using nested fetch API calls to get the product URL**

If you want more about details product image `URL` then You can use the `wordpress` media `url` endpoint to get `featured_image` url of your `woo-commerce` products.

Add this code in your `fetch` request. First fetch all the `products` and `featured_media` then loop through it and get all the `source_url` - you can save the urls based on product id in a `new array` in your `react` State

```
fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/product")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    //setProducts(data); //set state
    //loop through each data to get featured_media number
    data.forEach((x) => {
      //get all urls using featured_media
        fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/media/"+x.featured_media)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((o) => {
          //get all urls OR store to react State
          console.log(o.source_url)
      });
    })
});
```